# How to use Varnish to cache home page that serves different content to different user in different location?

Tags: caching, varnish

I run a location-based marketplace site and I'm planning to use Varnish to cache most of the pages. The thing is that my home page will show different content for different user within different location.

This location is detected by two ways. The default way is to translate the user's IP to the location and store the location in the session. The second way is when a page is loaded, the browser will ask the user's location using browser geolocation if it's not already done. Then that browser geolocation value will override the default geoip location, and the page will be refreshed.

Users with different location will see different product offered nearby the users. Usually the list of products in a homepage for a certain location will be refreshed every ten minutes.

Before I use Varnish for this, I want to ask. Will I get great performance benefit by using Varnish to cache my homepage given that condition? And how to do that? What are some other considerations? Let's say, will it on the contrary reduce the performance having a lot of cache miss for locations that rarely got visited.

Answer (score 0):

As such what you describe is a scenario which Varnish can handle, you probably will have to force a page reload if the browser geolocation is different to the IP-based location, plus you want to avoid to the use of sesions for the location and instead rely on a cookie.

If it will give you a lot of benefits performance wise depends on your traffic and how many country combinations you have. But a cache misses should not give a decreased performance compared to not using varnish.